# Generating CIGAR strings for MSA with reference

Tags: python, cigar

I have a list containing the results of a MSA:

```py
msa = [
    '-G-ATG-CGGATACCG-', # reference sequence
    'CGTATCTCG--TACCGA',
    '-GTATCTCGT-GACCG-',
    'CG-AT--CGG-GACCGA',
    '---AT--CG--GACCGA',
    '-GTAT---GC-GACCG-',
    'CG-AT--CGG-GACCGA',
    'CGTAT--CG--GA CG-',
]
```

I would like to generate the CIGAR strings of those alignments (against the reference sequence); the expected result would be something like:

```py
cigars = [
    '13M',
    '1I1M1I3M1I2M2D5M1I',
    '1M1I3M1I3M1D5M',
    '1I3M1D3M1D5M1I',
    '1D2M1D2M2D5M1I',
    '1M1I2M2D2M1D5M',
    '1I3M1D3M1D5M1I',
    '1I1M1I2M1D2M2D5M',
]
```

I don't know what would be a good approach for this. I managed to get the "aligned pairs" of each alignment but I don't think that'll help for determining the cigar strings:

```py
# mapping = position in alignment => position in reference
mapping = {y: x for x,y in enumerate(y for y,nuc in enumerate(msa[0]) if nuc != '-')}

for aln in msa:
    aligned_pairs = [(y, mapping[z]) for y,z in enumerate(z for z,nuc in enumerate(aln) if nuc != '-') if z in mapping]
    print(aligned_pairs)
```

```py
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7), (8, 8), (9, 9), (10, 10), (11, 11), (12, 12)]
[(1, 0), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 3), (7, 4), (8, 5), (9, 8), (10, 9), (11, 10), (12, 11), (13, 12)]
[(0, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 6), (9, 8), (10, 9), (11, 10), (12, 11), (13, 12)]
[(1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 8), (8, 9), (9, 10), (10, 11), (11, 12)]
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 5), (4, 8), (5, 9), (6, 10), (7, 11), (8, 12)]
[(0, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 8), (7, 9), (8, 10), (9, 11), (10, 12)]
[(1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 8), (8, 9), (9, 10), (10, 11), (11, 12)]
[(1, 0), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 4), (6, 5), (7, 8), (8, 9), (9, 10), (10, 11), (11, 12)]
```

How can I generate the CIGAR strings efficiently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you loop through the characters of two aligned sequences **in parallel** then you can easily determine the operations that compose the CIGAR. Then you just have to "collapse" the generated list of operations:

```py
import itertools

ref = msa[0]

for aln in msa:
    cig = []

    for i,nuc in enumerate(aln):
        if nuc != '-':
            if ref[i] != '-':
                cig.append('M')
            else:
                cig.append('I')
        elif ref[i] != '-':
                cig.append('D')

    cig = [(len(list(it)), op) for op,it in itertools.groupby(cig)]

    print( ''.join(str(n) + op for n,op in cig) )
```

```py
13M
1I1M1I3M1I2M2D5M1I
1M1I3M1I3M1D5M
1I3M1D3M1D5M1I
1D2M1D2M2D5M1I
1M1I2M2D2M1D5M
1I3M1D3M1D5M1I
1I1M1I2M1D2M2D5M
```